# Fill Dropdown option values from API MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a API that is called when dropdown value changes. It returns JSON results and I would like to update another dropdown from those JSON results but I keep getting an error in my Jquery

Razor View Page

```
<div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerProfile.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerProfile.Country, Model.CountryList, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "profileCountry", @class = "form-control col-md-2" , @onchange = "FillState()" })
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerProfile.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerProfile.State, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "StateFullName", "StateFullName"),
                  "Select State",
                  htmlAttributes: new { @id = "profileState", @class = "form-control col-md-2" })
     </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Script

```
<script>
  function FillState() {
      var countryParam = $('#profileCountry').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/CountryToState/FillState',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { country: countryParam},
        success: function (states) {
            $("#profileState").html(""); // clear before appending new list
            $.each(states, function (i, statetest) {
                $("#profileState").append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(statetest.StateFullName).html(statetest.StateFullName));
            });
        }
    });
  }
</script>
```

API Code

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public ActionResult FillState(string country)
        {
            var states = _context.CountryToState.Where(c => c.CountryName == country);
            return new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = states,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
```

CountryToState Model

```
 public class CountryToState
    {
        [Column("lngStateID")]
        [Key]
        public Int32 StateID { get; set; }

        [Column("strCountry")]
        public string CountryName { get; set; }

        [Column("strStateFullName")]
        public string StateFullName { get; set; }
}
```

It keeps giving me an error on Cannot read property 'StateFullName' of null. states returned in success function has 36 rows with StateFullName of every row. Why it is null. How can I fix this. I want value and text to be StateFullName in the drop down.

I do not understand the .each function properly

Console.Log(states) show the following:

```
ContentEncoding: null, ContentType: null, Data: Array(36), JsonRequestBehavior: 0, MaxJsonLength: null, …}
ContentEncoding: null
ContentType: null
Data: (36) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
JsonRequestBehavior: 0
MaxJsonLength: null
RecursionLimit: null
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Please edit the question to share the code for your API `/api/CountryToState/FillState`

Comment: @PriyankPanchal Done. Can you please help me with this

Comment: We will need one more thing, please add `CountryToState` model's properties. Does it contain a property named `StateFullName`?

Comment: @PriyankPanchal It does

Comment: Ok, are you sure your API is hit? Did you try to put a breakpoint on `FillState()`? can you see all your states in the `states` variable?

Comment: @PriyankPanchal yes it is filled in correctly and returns all the states. Is the view correct for my state

Comment: Try doing `console.log(states)` in your ajax `success` callback. What does it show? You can see the console in your browser's devtools. Usually `F12` on chrome.

Comment: Just deleted my answer because @PriyankPanchal 's question made me realize you do not have to navigate to states.Data.

Comment: @CiubotariuFlorin updated the question with results of console.log(states)

Comment: @PriyankPanchal   updated the question with results of console.log(states)

Comment: Apologies, @CiubotariuFlorin. You were right in your answer. The question still remains. Why it gave `statetest` null instead of `statetest.StateFullName` undefined.

Comment: No problem @PriyankPanchal. I even tested the OP's code on my machine and it wasn't necessary to navigate to `Data` property. I suppose that the jQuery/MVC version matters.

Comment: @CiubotariuFlorin I am using MVC version 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Reviewed your code and I think the error originates from ajax success function

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/CountryToState/FillState',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { country: countryParam},
    success: function (states) {
        $("#profileState").html(""); // clear before appending new list
        $.each(states, function (i, statetest) {
            $("#profileState").append(
                $('<option></option>').val(statetest.StateFullName).html(statetest.StateFullName));
        });
    }
});
```

In the code above I think that **state** parameter in success callback has such a structure:

```
{
  ContentEncoding: ...
  ContentEncoding: ...
  ContentType: ...
  Data: (36) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, 
             {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, 
             {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  JsonRequestBehavior: ...
  MaxJsonLength: ...
  RecursionLimit: ...
}
```

so you need to make a loop in **states.Data** instead of states :

```
$.each(states.Data, function (i, statetest) {
            $("#profileState").append(
                $('<option></option>').val(statetest.StateFullName).html(statetest.StateFullName));
        });
```